# Rerender <div> in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, html

I am creating a filter row kind of thing which takes the field name as parameter and criteria to filter the record.
I want to create one "Add Filter" button which basically creates new row with the  "field name, condition, value, Remove row(hyperlink)" row.
I tried few methods but did not worked

```
<ul class="slds-button-group slds-m-left--xx-small small oneActionsRibbon forceActionsContainer">
    <li class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-truncate">
        <a onclick="{!c.createFilterRow}" title="Add filter" class="forceActionLink">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Add filter">Add filter</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Button code

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-has" role="listitem" style=""> 
        <div class="uiInput">
            <label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel">
                <span class="">Filter field</span>
            </label>
            <lightning:select aura:id="select-FilterOption" class="ltng-label-hide">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.sObjectFilterOption}" var="item">
                    <option label="{!filter.Label}" value="{!filter.Value}" selected="{!filter.selected}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="slds-has" role="listitem" style="">
        <div class="uiInput>
            <label class="label">
                <span class="">Operator</span>
            </label>
            <lightning:select aura:id="select-Operators" class="ltng-label-hide" >
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.sObjectOperators}" var="item">
                    <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!item.Label}" text="{!item.Value}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="slds-has" role="listitem" style="">
        <div class="uiInput">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="">Value</span>
            </label>
            <ui:inputText class="input" aura:id="select-filterOption"/>                                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-has" role="listitem" style="">
        <div class="uiInput">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="" >Remove Row</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <a class="ltng-label-hide" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="{!c.removeFilterRow}">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

DIV part which i wanted to create on click of "Add Filter" button.

```
createFilterRow : function(component, event, helper) {
    var filterRowCount =  component.get('v.filterListCounter');
    filterRowCount++;
    component.set('v.filterListCounter',filterRowCount);
},
removeFilterRow : function(component, event, helper) {
}, 
rerender : function(component, event, helper) {
    this.superRerender();
    component.set('v.filterListCounter',filterRowCount);
}
```

Not sure what to write in controller function.

Can we use rerender option that we have in visualforce page?

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning it's different than VF and all about components attributes which are smart enough to handle the rerendering on their own.

Conceptually I would create the filter rows as an attribute of type Object[] and use aura:iteration to render the rows.

Now if you set this attribute to a new value containing more or less or different filter rows, the framework will rerender the aura:iteration automatically. It will even rerender the iteration if you set the attribute to it's current and unchanged value.

In other words: cmp.set() triggers a rerendering of everything where the attribute is used in the markup. This is quite powerful. You don't need to tell the framework to rerender a certain div or panel. It knows already. Even if you used the attribute multiple times cluttered over the screen: each place gets updated in the DOM.

So using cmp.set() is the new rerender.

Comment: Thanks I just started using lightning so was not much aware of.
I tried doing that but I was not able to.. can you help me little bit more on this?

Comment: I took an attribute with type as Object[] and on button click I am calling createRow function in my controller. 
Not sure what to do after that. Please help me